# Sending correct file size with PHP download script

Tags: php, cross-browser, browser, download

I created a file download script in PHP, it works, but web browsers report the file as "Unknown Length".  My code is as follows:

```
function downloadFile($file){
  // Set up the download system...
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($file));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

  // Flush the cache
  ob_clean();
  flush();

  // Send file to browser
  readfile($file);

  // DO NOT DO ANYTHING AFTER FILE DOWNLOAD
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Originally from http://paul.luminos.nl/update/471:

> The [CrimsonBase website](http://www.crimsonbase.com/) verifies downloads by passing them through a robust PHP script similar to the one published by Andrew Johnson in [his article about PHP-controlled file downloads](http://elements.nukamedia.com/v/Forcing-File-Downloads-with-PHP-Regardless-of-File-Type).
>
> Andrew makes a very important comment at the end of the article:
>
> > "If you compress files with Zlib, mod_deflate and so on the Content-Length header won't be accurate so you'll end up seeing "Unknown size" and "Unknown time remaining" when downloading files."
>
> I would like to stress this: if your browser doesn't appear to be obeying the headers generated by your PHP script—especially `Content-Length`—it is fairly likely that Apache's `mod_deflate` extension is enabled.
>
> You can easily disable it for a single script using the following line in an applicable `.htaccess` file:
>
> ```
> SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/download\.php no-gzip dont-vary
> ```
>
> where download.php is here assumed to be in the download script located in the server's root directory path (e.g. `www.crimsonbase.com/download.php`). (That's because the regular expression is `^/download\.php`.)

Comment: Thank you, I was getting "gzip" content type in my download and was able to get rid of it with your htaccess line, now I can see the download progress again because total file size is read correctly by the browser.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem, and I fixed it by sending the `Content-Length` header before the `Content-Disposition`.

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_url));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not flushing the cache before readfile() function. My code is almost identical to yours otherwise, and works fine.

Comment: Tried that, nothing.  The download still works fine, it's just that web browsers will say "unknown file size" even though I gave it a "Content-length".  Thing is, if I use wget, it reports the correct file size.