# Running a PHP script prior to direct access to an mp3 file

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, file-access

I am trying to add stats to Google Analytics regarding direct accesses of mp3 files (eg by iTunes) on this server.  I want to run this PHP function and deliver the file as though there had been no redirection.

The mod_rewrite piece of this seems to be functioning fine.  My onsite download scripts and streaming player can access mp3 files without triggering the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^audio/episodes/([^/\.]+).mp3$ /audio/episodes/google_analytics_mp3.php?mp3=$1&redirected=1 [L,QSA]
```

However my initial attempt at delivering mp3 after PHP script runs does not deliver file for direct accesses.  Just a white screen in a browser and an error in iTunes.

```
if ($id = intval($_REQUEST['mp3'])) {
    $e = new Episode;
    list($ep) = $e->retrieve("id = $id");   
    if ($ep) { 
        ga_send_pageview(basename($ep->audio_link), $ep->google_title()); 
        if ($_GET['redirected'] == 1) {
            $fileLocation = '/'.$ep->audio_link;
            header("Location: $fileLocation"); 
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Also tried sending `header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');` before the location header.  Same result.

My second attempt makes browser download file as attachment which will not work for programs like iTunes and is not desired result.

```
if ($_GET['redirected'] == 1) {
    $fileName = basename($ep->audio_link); 
    $fileLocation = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/audio/episodes/'.$filename;
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($fileLocation));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($fileLocation);
    exit();
}
```

**Update:** Per Martin's suggestion also tried this second approach but with disposition set to inline `header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$fileName.'"');` but Chrome just shows white screen. If I disable rule to remove script from equation Chrome will show native mp3 player and play file.

How can I simply allow the normal access to mp3 file after PHP script runs?

Comment: Utilize a cookie.

Comment: try `Content-Disposition: inline` to load the Mp3 into the browser or into iTunes directly rather than forcing it as a download.

Comment: @Martin to which approach?  With location header or second approach ?

Comment: I was understanding that ITunes was calling your script but not able to load your mp3? I was offering the idea that as the data is set as an attachment this would clash with what ITunes expects?

Comment: Gotcha. I tried just now changing attachment to inline ` header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');` and browser has same response to direct access- white screen.  Once rule is disabled taking script out of middle mp3 shows in Chrome's native player.

Comment: Yes, no errors are being logged from this. Digging more, going to add some output to dump what script is seeing...

Comment: I take it that solved it. Awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously had issues with `Content-length:` , you can try commenting out this line. I think the filesystem filesize reader is different from the browser filesize quantifier so the browser expects (and gets) 99% of the file which is obviously then incomplete so then it can't output the file as it perceives it as incomplete data.

```
File System File Size as read !== browser file size
```

However I'm not certain why this is so .

Comment: @jerrygarciuh edit as an additional : [filesize inconsistency](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2429162/3536236)